# Per Application config file bindingRedirect doesn't apply to Dlls

Tags: windows, manifest, sxs

I created a simple Win32 application to demonstrate UXtheme on XP by including a manifest dependency on the ver 6 commctl32.dll
I then created a simple Win32 dll, built it with `ISOLATION_AWARE_ENABLED`, and tested it with an embedded manifest specifying both version 5 and 6 of Comctl32.dll

I successfully got the exe and dll to use different versions of comctl32.dll using this method. Both with the exe using 5 and the dll version 6, and the other way around.

Then, I reset the app AND the dll to have a comctl ver 5 manifest dependency. And introduced an application configuration file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<configuration>
  <windows>
    <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity type="win32" name="Microsoft.Windows.Common-Controls" processorArchitecture="amd64" publicKeyToken="6595b64144ccf1df"/>
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="5.82.7100.0" newVersion="6.0.0.0"/>
      </dependentAssembly>
    </assemblyBinding>
  </windows>
</configuration>
```

Now, when I run my application, the applications is clearly being redirected to commctl v6 - dialogs are clearly displayed using the XP UXTheme enabled.
However, the dll is not being redirected and is using the non themed ver 5 of commctl.

There is no mention of per-dll config files for doing bindingRedirects in the documentation. And trying to create one does not do anything.

I do also know that doing a bindingRedirect from one major version of an assembly to another is not a supported scenario, but Im really just using commctl32 as an obvious easy way to test the mechanics.

How do I redirect the version of a dependent assembly of a dll?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So, this question has been answered.

- I used Process Monitor to track file access,
- After realizing that accesses to .manifest and .config files come from the csrss.exe NOT my own process,
- And Windows Vista won't even access .manifest or .config files that are added later as it caches their existence along with a date-time stamp for the exe.

After all that I discovered that LoadLibrary does probe for a .config file when loading dlls:

```
full_path_to_dll\dllname.dll.2.config
```

Binding redirects in this file will be processed.

Comment: Thanks, this saved me hours. Is this documented anywhere?

Answer (score 4):

> And Windows Vista won't even access .manifest or .config files that
>   are added later as it caches their existence along with a date-time
>   stamp for the exe.

I've found that logging off/on seems to clear the triggers the config file to be read again.